# Can't open a Python interpreter in Spyder 2.2.5 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, spyder

A few weeks ago, I opened Spyder and found that I could not interact with the default Python interpreter console, which appeared greyed-out (screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of uninteractive console]

Consequently, I am not able to run Python scripts from within the IDE. I have tried rebooting my machine, opening new interpreters and IPython interpreters, but the result is always the same. I recently tried running `spyder --reset` in the terminal to erase my settings, but it did not help.

The only recent changes to my Python installation I made were in a `virtualenv` where I installed Python3, but I am not convinced this is related.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, also after updating packages. I solved the problem by updating Spyder:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade spyder
```